# Representation in conceptual model

Tags: data-modeling, datamodel

in an OLTP conceptual model, when relating two entities, do we consider relationship "at a given point in time" or "throughout the life of entity"?

Eg: A Workitem can go thru multiple status (open , inprogress, closed), but at a given point in time it can be associated to only one status.

a) Will this be represented as Many-to-Many between status entity and workitem entity, given workitem can be associated to multiple status over its life?

b) Will this be represented as one-to-Many between status entity and workitem entity, given workitem can be associated to one status at a given point in time?

c) Will this be represented as one-to-Many between workitem-status entity(juntion table) and workitem entity, given workitem can be associated to one workitem+status combo at a given point in time? (I think this will not be conceptual but physical)

d) will status not be shown in conceptual at all and simply an attribute?

Thanks
Sunny